# Finding files with lines of length greater than 500 characters

Tags: python, file, io

I'm in need of some help. I need to create a function that will parse through text files with lines of 500 characters or longer. The code I wrote is below:

```
import os
from os.path import join
place = raw_input('Enter path: ')
for f in os.listdir(place):
    newlist = []
    if f.endswith(".txt"):
            newlist.append(f)
    for i in newlist:
        with open(join(place, i)) as fi:
            for line in fi:
                if len(line) > 350:
                    print(place, i)
```

So the idea is to print the location of the file and the name of the file if the length is above 500. However, it doesn't seem to be doing that, as I know of a file with greater than 700 that it's simply not finding. Any ideas?

Comment: put `newlist = []` before the main for loop, plus, I guess you need to run the second for loop when the first finishes

Comment: Define "characters". It variously may mean: bytes, code units, code points, legacy grapheme clusters, extended grapheme clusters, glyphs, ...

Comment: That actually worked, thanks @MedAli

Comment: @DarpanGanatra It may be a stop gap solution, but I recommend looking at my answer if you want to improve your code...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ actually trying your solution out right now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to put `newlist = []` before the for loops otherwise it's getting emptied in each iteration.
2. Run the second for loop after the first one finishes so that `newlist` gets populated before you iterate through it.

---

Here's how the code looks like after the suggested edits:

```
import os
from os.path import join
place = raw_input('Enter path: ')

newlist = []

for f in os.listdir(place):
    if f.endswith(".txt"):
            newlist.append(f)

for i in newlist:
    with open(join(place, i)) as fi:
        for line in fi:
            if len(line) > 350:
                print(place, i)
```

Answer (score 1):

This keeps a cumulative count of the length of each line. Once this exceeds 350, it appends the filename to the list of results and continues searching.

```
import os

place = raw_input('Enter path: ')
text_files = [f for f in os.listdir(place) if f.endswith('.txt')]
results = []
for f in text_files:
    with open(os.path.join(place, f)) as fin:
        count = 0
        for line in fin:
            count += len(line)
            if count > 350:
                results.append(f)
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get the size of file as initially mentioned in question description

```
import os
b = os.path.getsize("/path/filename.fileextension")
if len(b) > 500:
   ...
```

but if you want the line length as I edited and as it is mentioned on the question title go with other approach (actually yours is ok)

```
with open("/path/filename.ext") as f:
  for line in f:
    if len(line) > 500:
      ...
      # Where you can do it
```

Comment: This is not what OP is looking for. They want to find files with lines of length over 500, not total size 500.

Comment: @COLDSPEED just read the question if you can, anywhere says files with line length more that 500????

Comment: @COLDSPEED Ok, sorry